# Сложность выполнения команды для пользователя

Tags: ui

Давно видел таблицу с среднем временем требуемым на какое-либо действие. Например нажатие на клавишу оценивается в 0,2 с, взять в руки мышку и навести на нужное место 1,2 с.
Хочется описать временные затраты пользователя для достижения задачи. Например 20 нажатий на клавиатуру и 2 клика мышью ~ 6,4 с.
Буду весьма благодарен если подскажете как это называется.

Answer (score 2):

Анализ эффективности пользовательского интерфейса: критерии качества интерфейса, закон Фитса, закон Хика, метод GOMS.

1. http://rybanoff.narod.ru/transl/ot_lection_8.pdf
2. http://www.mrwolf.ru/Kompyutery_i_soft/Pro4ee/11629
3. http://studopedia.ru/8_114159_analiz-effektivnosti-polzovatelskogo-interfeysa.html